# What is wrong with this SAS code?

Tags: proc-sql, fcmp

I copy the code from a paper that i found on internet.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.Test; 
     function whatAmI(); 
        return(42);
     endsub;
quit;

options cmplib=work.funcs;

data _null_;
    rci = whatAmI();
    put rci=; /* should be 42 */
run;
```

When I execute the code, it show the message:
ERROR 68-185: The function WHATAMI is unknown, or cannot be accessed.

I tried other functions and always show this message.
I change the libname, but nothing work.
What´s wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Aditya.

Seems like 9.2 has the ability to actually *use* functions, while 9.1.3 only has the ability to more or less *create* them.

Check out [THIS THREAD](http://www.listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0705d&L=sas-l&P=58123) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with the version. Make sure you are using SAS 9.2, since previous versions have a limited support of PROC FCMP.